# mediaelement.js - Trigger from php in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to launch MediaElement.js using returns from a database.

If I put `[audio src="http://www.soundtheology.org/HA-mp3/DA-1430.mp3"]`
on a page, it launches the player.

But when that same code is produced by php combining copy with the database return, it simply prints out on the screen and the player does not launch.

Is there a way to bring the copy up with php and still launch the player?

I'm using WordPress and pulling the data from an online database.

Answer (score 0):

Within a Wordpress template page, you must wrap shortcodes with `do_shortcode()` like so:

```
   <?php echo do_shortcode('[audio src="http://www.soundtheology.org/HA-mp3/DA-1430.mp3"]'); ?>
```

Hope that helps!